# Use AutoIt to call another AutoIt compiled executable with parameters

Tags: parameters, tooltip, parameter-passing, executable, autoit

I was trying to create a program that would use multiple tooltips, but I came across a problem: I can only use one at a time, because after that, the new one will replace the previous.

I came up with a solution: Compile a program that creates a tooltip and use it as much as needed. But then there is another problem: I want the tooltips in different positions and with different texts/titles.

To do that I need to use parameters or other types of variables that would change the coordinates and text of the tooltip.

My called exe would perform something very simple like:

```
ToolTip($text, $x, $y, $title, 0, 1 + 4)
Sleep(10000)
```

There is probably a quicker/easier way to do it.

Comment: Why not creating little GUIs? Then you can place them wherever you want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make use of the `/AutoIt3ExecuteLine` command line option, which allows you to run 1 line of code from the command line. At its simplest you could implement it like this:

```
_ShowAnotherTooltip(1000, "Hello", 100, 100)
_ShowAnotherTooltip(1000, "World", 200, 200)


Func _ShowAnotherTooltip($time, $text, $x = Default, $y = Default, $title = "", $icon = Default, $options = Default)
    Local $cmd = StringFormat("ToolTip(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", "'" & $text & "'", $x, $y, "'" & $title & "'", $icon, $options)

    Run("""" & @AutoItExe & """ /AutoIt3ExecuteLine ""Sleep(" & $cmd & "*0+" & $time & ")""")
EndFunc   ;==>_ShowAnotherTooltip
```

Only real trickery here is getting the tooltip and sleep on one line. The code generated will look something like:

```
Sleep(ToolTip('Hello', 100, 100, '', Default, Default)*0+1000)
```

Depending on how good your computer is, you will probably see a noticeable delay between the two tooltips showing. If you want to have them all show at the same time then the code gets a bit more complicated:

```
If $CmdLine[0] And $CmdLine[1] = "/ExecuteLine" Then
    ; This is the child script

    ; Wait for the window to appear
    WinWait($CmdLine[2])

    ; Then execute the line.
    Execute($CmdLine[3])

    Exit
EndIf

_AddAnotherTooltip(1000, "Hello", 100, 100)
_AddAnotherTooltip(1000, "World", 200, 200)

_ShowTheTooltips()



Func _ShowTheTooltips()
    GUICreate("ShowThoseTooltipsNow")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>_ShowTheTooltips

Func _AddAnotherTooltip($time, $text, $x = Default, $y = Default, $title = "", $icon = Default, $options = Default)
    Local $cmd = StringFormat("ToolTip(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", "'" & $text & "'", $x, $y, "'" & $title & "'", $icon, $options)

    Local $iPid
    If @Compiled Then
        $iPid = Run("""" & @AutoItExe & """ /ExecuteLine ShowThoseTooltipsNow ""Sleep(" & $cmd & "*0+" & $time & ")""")
    Else
        $iPid = Run("""" & @AutoItExe & """ """ & @ScriptFullPath & """ /ExecuteLine ShowThoseTooltipsNow ""Sleep(" & $cmd & "*0+" & $time & ")""")
    EndIf

    ProcessWait($iPid)
EndFunc   ;==>_AddAnotherTooltip
```

There are better methods of interprocess communication but this one is very simple.

Finally, there is probably a better way to do it using the *GUITooltip** functions.